# Which module in linux 2.6 kernel should I modify to count the number of ip packets sent/received?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel, kernel-module

I need to modify a kernel module(s) to count number of packets that the machine has sent / received over my wireless adapter for the linux 2.6 kernel. Please let me know which modules should I modify. Any references would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I am not very sure about wireless adapter, but I think it is similar to a wired one. For wired and wireless NIC, you can use ifconfig eth0 command, then in the output, you will see one or two lines telling you the number of packets sent(TX) or received(RX).

To get the same information from the kernel module, one way is to modify the device driver for the network card. One tutorial about rtl8139 (wired one) is here: http://linuxgazette.net/156/jangir.html

Also, I think there are some standard kernel interface that you can use to get the same info. For example, `tp->stats.tx_packets` mentioned in the above link.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in IP packets you should consider creating a kernel module that uses netfilter hooks. It's very simple, here take a look at this:

http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-hacking-HOWTO-3.html

Netfilter is primarily intended for firewalling, but it can do what you want and you don't need to mess with other kernel modules. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /proc/net/dev
```

is probably not what you want, but then explain why.

Comment: actually I want to make a useful proc file system module myself.Also that way I would get a chance to look into the network drivers as well. But the code looks overwhelming.

Comment: then your question is not specific enough... I mean, you can probably start here: http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/net/ipv4/proc.c